# how can i Check if at least 3 out of 5 conditions are True in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements

How can I create a code in r that if at least 3 of the 5 conditions are true then it can print "SCM"?

I've tried running this code but then I get this error message:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `SCM`.
>
> x Input `SCM` must be a vector, not a `formula` object.
>
> i Input `SCM` is `~...`.

```
datosB_graficas <- datosB_mice %>% mutate(SCM=case_when (((TG > 150) + (Glucosa_mg > 110) + 
                                               (Per.Cintura > 88) + (PAS > 130) + 
                                               (PAD> 88) + (HDL<40 )) >= 3)~ {"SCM"},
                                                  TRUE~ "Sano" )
```

```
structure(list(PAS = c(130, 100, 151, 134, 125, 146, 145, 127, 
109, 115), PAD = c(94, 61, 79, 74, 78, 88, 78, 92, 71, 68), Per.Cintura = c(95.9, 
101, 83.1, 103.2, 96.9, 94.4, 110.9, 92.8, 76.6, 77.3), HDL = c(38, 
48, 40, 70, 45, 39, 44, 51, 57, 51), TG = c(152, 92, 181, 99, 
103, 198, 166, 76, 111, 106), Glucosa_mg = c(74, 85, 91, 92, 
88, 86, 117, 85, 79, 85)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data with dput() and provide results of str(datosB_mice)?

Comment: Please provide some sample data, and desired output

Comment: The idea of your code looks good - I think you have parenthesis problems. Share some sample data as requested above and we can help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use as.numeric to convert each True and False into 0 or 1.

```
datosB_mice%>%mutate(SCM=case_when(as.numeric(TG>150) + as.numeric(Glucosa_mg > 110) + as.numeric(Per.Cintura > 88) + as.numeric(PAS > 130) + as.numeric(PAD> 88) + as.numeric (HDL<40 ) >=3 ~ "SCM", TRUE ~ "Sano"))

   PAS PAD Per.Cintura HDL  TG Glucosa_mg  SCM
1  130  94        95.9  38 152         74  SCM
2  100  61       101.0  48  92         85 Sano
3  151  79        83.1  40 181         91 Sano
4  134  74       103.2  70  99         92 Sano
5  125  78        96.9  45 103         88 Sano
6  146  88        94.4  39 198         86  SCM
7  145  78       110.9  44 166        117  SCM
8  127  92        92.8  51  76         85 Sano
9  109  71        76.6  57 111         79 Sano
10 115  68        77.3  51 106         85 Sano
```

Comment: If i wanted to add a factor should i use as.numeric too?

Comment: @AngelaArangoGonzalez Yes add another as.numeric.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the optimal solution, but you could run a loop through these conditions and have an iterator, let's call it k, checking to see if they are true or not and adding one to k if any condition is true. Then, if k is >= 3 by the end of the loop, you'll know that 3/5 conditions are satisfied.

Comment: OP's idea in the question of adding the logicals and testing `>= 3` is better than a  loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work

```
datosB_graficas <- datosB_mice %>% mutate(SCM = case_when(as.numeric(TG > 150) + as.numeric(Glucosa_mg > 110) +  as.numeric(Per.Cintura > 88) + as.numeric(PAS > 130) +  as.numeric(PAD> 88) + as.numeric(HDL<40 ) >= 3 ~ "SCM", 
                                          TRUE~ "Sano" ))

#OR
datosB_graficas <- datosB_mice %>% mutate(SCM = case_when(+(TG > 150) + +(Glucosa_mg > 110) +  +c(Per.Cintura > 88) + +(PAS > 130) +  +(PAD> 88) + +(HDL<40 ) >= 3 ~ "SCM", 
                                          TRUE~ "Sano" ))

> datosB_graficas
   PAS PAD Per.Cintura HDL  TG Glucosa_mg  SCM
1  130  94        95.9  38 152         74  SCM
2  100  61       101.0  48  92         85 Sano
3  151  79        83.1  40 181         91 Sano
4  134  74       103.2  70  99         92 Sano
5  125  78        96.9  45 103         88 Sano
6  146  88        94.4  39 198         86  SCM
7  145  78       110.9  44 166        117  SCM
8  127  92        92.8  51  76         85 Sano
9  109  71        76.6  57 111         79 Sano
10 115  68        77.3  51 106         85 Sano
```

Comment: I´ve tried your code and I got this message: Error in splice(dot_call(capture_dots, frame_env = frame_env, named = named,  : 
  objeto 'TG' no encontrado

Comment: check it now please